# How to fix "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Before I used Python 3.x 32bit, I installed Python 3.x 64bit and uninstalled the 32-bit version. However, when I use Pycharm to run a simple program as follows, Python reports an error (see screenshot below).

I tried adding an environment variable to the path.

With ASCII characters, Pycharm can run normally, but I want to code Vietnamese, then Pycharm shows this error.

How do I fix this?

This is my screenshot of Pycharm Community 2018.3.2 64 bit with Python 3.7.2 64bit:

[image: PyCharm]

Comment: Does it work when you run out directly in a console instead of in the IDE? Python 3.6 and later *should* be using UTF-8 properly ... does passing `-X` to the interpreter help?

Comment: I can type in python shell, so what should I do to fix IDE Pycharm error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 4336: character maps to <undefined>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40194968/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x90-in-position-4336-cha)

Answer (score 0):

`open(encoding="utf8")`

Comment: adding a verbal explanation is helpful